# Is there such a notion as broadening where find searches?

Tags: find, python, path

I'm trying to identify redundant installations of the site package `matplotlib` in my python3.5 environment.

A contributor to the library [(GitHub issue)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6492#issuecomment-223286337) is advising that I use

> python3.5 -m site

to identify the paths in the environment of python3.5 that are searched when using the `find` command like so:
`find ./ -name matplotlib`

This implies that `find` is somehow related to `PATH` (which seems fair), but no online reference seems to explain how. If there is a relationship, then, in particular, I'd like to *broaden* the paths where `find` searches for redundancies of `matplotlib` in my environment.

Just for reference, this is what happens using terminal:

```
Anjalis-MBP:~ ahanagrawal$ python3.5 -m site
sys.path = [
    '/Users/ahanagrawal',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/ahanagrawal/Library/Python/3.5' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/ahanagrawal/Library/Python/3.5/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: AFAIK `find` searches precisely the directories you tell it to (with the possible exception of descent into foreign filesystems, depending on option flags such as `-xdev`). Did you really mean to search `./` (only the current directory), or did you perhaps intend to search `/` (the filesystem root directory)?

Comment: I don't see anything about `find` in the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `python3.5 -m site` then python searches for a file `site.py` in your `sys.path`. This `sys.path` is a list determined where your python is installed and by environment variables, and various other mechanisms including the ones to recognise packages installed under `site-packages`.

Now your `matplotlib` might be in one of those paths. But if you e.g. also have a python3.4 installation, it could be under that as well and the `python3.5 -m site` command will not display directory. So that advice is useless for finding all matplotlib installations.

Issuing `find ./ -name matplotlib` will find all files, directories, etc named `matplotlib` under the directory where you started searching. If you happen to be in the root directory `/` and have read access to all subdirectories you probably will find all `matplotlib` installations (assuming they have a file or directory name `matplotlib`). If you issue the command from somewhere else you will not. E.g. try

```
mkdir bla
cd bla
find ./ -name matplotlib
```

Guaranteed not to find matplotlib although you know it is installed.

You better try:

```
cd /
sudo find . -name matplotlib
```

There is no influence of your `PATH` environment variable on where `find` searches, and I have no idea why you state "This implies that find is somehow related to PATH"

Comment: Why is it helpful to identify where `site.py` is along `sys.path`, in order to identify installations of `matplotlib` in python3.5?

Comment: Because I've configured my IDE to use python3.5, my understanding is that I only need worry about redundant installations of `matplotlib` in my python3.5 environment. Hence, I take it that `python3.5 -m site` will do the trick? Although, like you suggested, if I were interested in finding `matplotlib` in all installations of python on my computer, then I should use the sudo command you posted.

Comment: @muno if you have just one installation of matplotlib and it works with 3.5 there are still a plethora of directories **where** it might be installed. The list of (most of) the directories, that is what you get with `python -m site`. Typical duplication occurs when you install a package with your system installer (`yum`, `apt-get`) and then also via `pip`.

Comment: @Anthonn There must be a more general reason as to why `python 3.5 -m site` finds most of the directories where `matplotlib` might be installed, however ?! :D Is it that `site.py` is often hidden (i.e it is not visible but exists) under `site-packages`? Thus, finding the location of `site.py` is an indirect way of finding `site-packages?`?

Comment: @Muno No, site.py has that functionality explictly built-in https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html (close to the bottom). And site.py is part of the standard library, not installed under site-packages.